# vim "put" to paste on same line

Tags: vim

In my function I want to paste some generated text there at the position of the cursor (in insert mode). I am using `put` to do so, however it pastes it on a new line. Is there a way to make put paste it on the same line? If not what is the proper command ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use `:put`, it will always use a new line. You have the following options:

1. Issue a normal-mode command to insert the text: `:execute "normal! amy text\<Esc>"`. This needs `:execute` to properly leave insert mode.
2. Assign your text to a register: `:let @@ = 'my text'` Then, use `:normal! p` (or `P`, optionally with prepended motions to position the cursor). Alternatively, use the *expression register*: `:execute "normal! \"='my text'\<CR>"`
3. From insert mode, you can also use `<C-r>{register}` or `<C-r>={expr}<CR>`.
4. Use `:setline()`, splicing in the new contents into the existing (`getline()`) line with the help of `strpart()`.

The first ones are easier, and usually what you want. The last is using a lower-level API, therefore more involved to use, but it doesn't trigger any messages, clobbers register contents, creates a separate change for undo, etc.

Comment: Let's say that my_text="value" contains the text. When I use normal! my_text I print "my_text" not the value of my_text. How can I print the value of my_text ?

Comment: Ah, that wasn't clear from the question. I've added more details to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the text to be inserted stored?

**Edit**

So, per your your comment, the text is stored in a variable. Assuming, the variable is `g:text`, then, while in insert mode, you press `ctrl-r` followed by `=` followed by `g:text`.

See also `help i_CTRL-R_=`

---

I leave the old answer here. Maybe someone else comes accros and finds it useful:

Assuming, it's in a register (as per your mentening `:put`), you press `CTRL-R` and then *register name* (for example `a`) - (while being in insert mode).

Comment: The text is stored inside a variable.